# Python finding some, not all custom packages

Tags: python, windows, python-3.5

I have a project with the following file structure:

```
root/
    run.py
    bot/
        __init__.py
        my_discord_bot.py
    dice/
        __init__.py
        dice.py
        # dice files
    help/
        __init__.py
        help.py
        # help files
    parser/
        __init__.py
        parser.py
        # other parser files
```

The program is run from within the `root` directory by calling `python run.py`. `run.py` imports `bot.my_discord_bot` and then makes use of a class defined there.

The file `bot/my_discord_bot.py` has the following import statements:

```
import dice.dice as d
import help.help as h
import parser.parser as p
```

On Linux, all three import statements execute correctly. On Windows, the first two seem to execute fine, but then on the third I'm told:

```
ImportError: No module named 'parser.parser'; 'parser' is not a package
```

Why does it break on the third `import` statement, and why does it only break on Windows?

**Edit:** clarifies how the program is run

Comment: Is it possible that you have different Python version on Linux and Windows? And if so, do you have do support both?

Comment: You mention that the first two imports "seem to execute fine", but if you comment out the `import parser.parser as p` line, do the other imports succeed? Also, do you need an `__init__.py` in your `root/`?

Comment: @DeepSpace I have the same Python version on both systems.

Comment: @elethan The other imports still succeed with the offending one commented out. I also don't get any changes if I add an `__init__.py` to my root directory.

Comment: Is the "root" directory in your PYTHONPATH environment variable?

Comment: @BradCampbell It isn't, but I should have clarified that the whole program is run by calling Python on a script placed in `root/`; I've updated the question.

Comment: Also, triple check that something didn't happen to your `__init__.py` in `parser/`, and that you are not shadowing a built-in or third-party library. For example, if I open a Python 3 interpreter and do `import parser` it is successful, even though I have not created a package called `parser` myself. Maybe just test if renaming the package solves the problem. I know it succeeded on Linux, but maybe you have another package called `parser` on your Windows install, but not the Linux one. http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap

Comment: @elethan It was a name clash with a system package; apparently Linux prefers the local one over the system, while Windows doesn't! Stick that in the form of an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your `parser` is not shadowing a built-in or third-party package/module/library.

I am not 100% sure about the specifics of how this name conflict would be resolved, but it seems like you can potentially a). have your module overridden by the existing module (which seems like it might be happening in your Windows case), or b). override the existing module, which could cause bugs down the road. It seems like **b** is what commonly trips people up.

If you think this might be happening with one of your modules (which seems fairly likely with a name like `parser`), try renaming your module.

See [this very nice article](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap) for more details and more common Python "import traps".

Answer (score 0):

Put run.py outside root folder, so you'll have run.py next to root folder, then create `__init__.py` inside root folder, and change imports to:

```
import root.parser.parser as p
```

Or just rename your parser module.

Anyway you should be careful with naming, because you can simply mess your own stuff someday.